# How IDE get the class hierarchy

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, reflection

although there is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871697/getting-the-class-hierarchy-in-java), but it was really long long ago. And I have no reputation to comment under that question.

My question is How IDE like IntelliJ to get the class hierarchy so efficiently? especially the subclasses.

of course I know some typical way like using the [Reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections). But it can only do this on runtime.

I want to build a tool myself that can get any project's class hierarchy outside the project and do this before runtime just like IntelliJ do.

Thanks for any reply!

Comment: Eclipse uses the [JDT Abstract Syntax Tree](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJDT/article.html)

Comment: Attn close voters - this is a fair question related to the internal indexing of java files by intellij. Please review my answer, close not needed here.

Comment: I'd like to add to @greg-449 's answer that the Eclipse JDT AST model, parsers and so on can be used in any Java program (not only in Eclipse IDE). Some other tools do use it for their Java navigation and refactorings.

Comment: @Mickael Hi, Where I can get the tutorial of using the JDT without building it as a eclipse plugin, the link provided above is really good but It is based on develope a eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ creates an *indexing* of all known classes for each intellij project.

This includes your own code, classes in libraries, and the JDK (java) classes.

You will notice the first time IntelliJ opens a project that it takes some seconds to index.

This allows intellij to quickly navigate from a class to (say) its superclass, subclasses and usages.

If you read the documentation for IntelliJ plugin development, you can gain access to the internal API and read about the `PSI` structure.

Link: https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/architectural_overview/psi_elements.html